# SHBrowseForFolderA Errors

Tags: c++

I recently found some code on here which shows us how to let users choose the directory in C++ which isn't as simple as C#. I keep getting three errors I barley understand. And i want to know how to store the path onto a string.

ERRORS:

```
argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWSTR"   

a value of type "const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "LPCWSTR"

no suitable constructor exists to convert from "TCHAR [260]" to "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>"
```

and here is the code i'm using:

```
int CALLBACK BrowseForFolderCallback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, LPARAM lp, LPARAM pData)
{
    char szPath[MAX_PATH];

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case BFFM_INITIALIZED:
        SendMessage(hwnd, BFFM_SETSELECTION, TRUE, pData);
        break;

    case BFFM_SELCHANGED:
        if (SHGetPathFromIDList((LPITEMIDLIST)lp, szPath))
        {
            SendMessage(hwnd, BFFM_SETSTATUSTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)szPath);

        }
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}

    static int CALLBACK BrowseCallbackProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, LPARAM lParam, LPARAM lpData)
    {
    
        if (uMsg == BFFM_INITIALIZED)
        {
            std::string tmp = (const char*)lpData;
            std::cout << "path: " << tmp << std::endl;
            SendMessage(hwnd, BFFM_SETSELECTION, TRUE, lpData);
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
    
    std::string BrowseFolder(std::string saved_path)
    {
        TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    
        const char* path_param = saved_path.c_str();
    
        BROWSEINFO bi = { 0 };
        bi.lpszTitle = ("Browse for folder...");
        bi.ulFlags = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS | BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE;
        bi.lpfn = BrowseCallbackProc;
        bi.lParam = (LPARAM)path_param;
    
        LPITEMIDLIST pidl = SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);
    
        if (pidl != 0)
        {
            //get the name of the folder and put it in path
            SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, path);
    
            //free memory used
            IMalloc* imalloc = 0;
            if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetMalloc(&imalloc)))
            {
                imalloc->Free(pidl);
                imalloc->Release();
            }
    
            return path;
        }
    
        return "";
    }
```

The First Error occurs in: **case BFFM_SELCHANGED**
The Second Error occurs in: **bi.lpszTitle = ("Browse for folder...");**
The Final Error occurs in: **return path;**

EDIT: The second and third error are fixed. However, the first one still remains and i have no clue how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add a L in front of the strings,  like that :
`bi.lpszTitle = (L"Browse for folder...");`
this will turn the string into a Wide String

Comment: Thank you! that removed one of my errors, i still have the first and last error still there :(

Comment: replace   `std::string BrowseFolder(std::string saved_path)`
by   `std::wstring BrowseFolder(std::string saved_path)`

Comment: and  `return "";`  by   `return L"";`

Comment: Now i still have the first error, and the third error is gone. However, it moved to the line -  return "";

Comment: Oh! now the errors are gone, however, i still have the first one at BFFM_SELECHANGED

Comment: in  BFFM_SETSELECTION  you mean ?   not sure about this one, maybe force the wideString, like that `SendMessageW(hwnd, BFFM_SETSELECTIONW, TRUE, lpData);`

Comment: Still doesn't work. To be more specific it's giving the error at `szPath` after the case

Comment: I don't see any  szPath  in your code,  I assume it's a string,  the idea is to force all your code to use  Widestring.  
so replace  string -> wstring ; 
make sure TCHAR are WCHAR  ;  
add some  L  in front of all string : L"example" ; 
and add some  W at the end of all Windows API  function when it's possible, example SendMessage ->  SendMessageW

Comment: replace ` char szPath[MAX_PATH];`  by  ` wchar_t szPath[MAX_PATH];`

Comment: Hi, i want to ask one last thing. the L is added before the string but what if it is predefined? ex. `string x = hi` . how do i add it to x? ex. `cout<< Lx<<endl;` understand my idea? i wanna add it to the variable not the text it self. how do i do that

Comment: L is only in front of  `L"string"` to specify to the compiler that you want "string" to be a WString .  It makes no sense to have it in front of variable, because the type of variable is defined during its creation.
for example,
`std::string  normalString;`
`std::wstring  wideString;`
`std::cout<< wideString;  //  <-- no need to add L, compiler knows you are using wstring.`

Answer (score 0):

in order to make this code compile with Visual Studio :
Project -> Properties -> Advanced -> Character Set = Use Multi-Byte ChararacterSet

Comment: I already have it set to that and the errors are still there

Comment: make sure you are setting it in the correct  Configuration/Platform ( at the top of the Property Page window )  for example if you are setting it for Release/x64,  but building with Debug/x64,  that won't be affected